# Inter VLAN Routing

Tags: routing, vlan, ip-routing

I have VLAN 1 and VLAN 2 setup on HP ProCurve Switch, each linked to a different scope on DHCP server.

VLAN1 = 10.220.0.0/23

VLAN2 = 10.210.0.0/21

I can't ping VLAN1 devices from VLAN2 and vice versa. I have ip-routing enabled and have a default-gateway defined. Below is my route list's currently. Is there some config I'm missing here?

```
                                IP Route Entries

  Destination        Gateway         VLAN Type      Sub-Type   Metric     Dist.
  ------------------ --------------- ---- --------- ---------- ---------- -----
  0.0.0.0/0          10.220.1.19     1    static               1          1
  10.210.0.0/21      Voice           2    connected            1          0
  10.220.0.0/23      Data            1    connected            1          0
  127.0.0.0/8        reject               static               0          0
  127.0.0.1/32       lo0                  connected            1          0
```